# Putting elements via array into a Listbox

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, listbox

first show my code:

```
datTable = new DataTable();
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [CustomerId] FROM
[DataSource]", connection);
sqlDatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
            sqlDatAdapter.Fill(datTable);
            customer.DisplayMember = "CustomerId";
            customerListbox.DataSource = datTable;
```

So that works fine to fill the Listbox with a column from a database in SQL. What I wanted to do is a loop where he automatically fills in more than one Listbox. It works for loop with the SQL Statements but how can I handle the line

```
customer.DisplayMember = "CustomerId"
```

Is there a way or have I to duplicate this piece of code over and over again and change the lines manually? I tried to create an array of objects and fill it with customer.DisplayMember etc but that does not work.

What I mean is: I will do this piece of code more than once and everytime just the Listbox and the SQL Column changes. So fill different Listboxes with different columns. So maybe an array or a list with objects like 
customer.DisplayMember, product.DisplayMember etc

Comment: what? please be more clear

Comment: Ok edited. Means I want to fill the first Listbox with a column "CostumerId", a second one with another column and so on. Can I do this somehow in a loop?

Comment: Add more code.  What is customer? ( in customer.DisplayMember )

Comment: Sorry. Should be "CustomerId"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you want to populate multiple list boxes. You could create a method to populate all the list boxes by passing in a dictionary of the list boxes/data member, and the datatable. Something like this:

```
    private void PopulateListBoxes(Dictionary<ListBox, string> ListBoxCollection, DataTable CustomerTable)
    {

        foreach(var key in ListBoxCollection.Keys)
        {
            key.DisplayMember = ListBoxCollection[key];
            key.DataSource = CustomerTable;
        }
    }
```

And you could call like this:

```
//this DataTable should contain data for all list boxes
sqlDatAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
Dictionary<ListBox, string> myListBoxes = new Dictionary<ListBox, string>();

//add your existing list boxes here with the corresponding data member
myListBoxes.Add(customerListBox, "CustomerID");
myListBoxes.Add(productListBox, "ProductID");
//add more here

PopulateListBoxes(myListBoxes, dataTable);
```

Comment: When I understand you right: I dont want to populate listboxes. They are already there. Just fill each one with a different row. The same amount of rows like listboxes.

Comment: This code will work for that. The first parameter in myListBoxes.Add() is the existing list box, the second parameter is the name of the display member for the specific list box.

Comment: Ok then I understand something wrong but then I have to write the SQL commands over and over again for each listbox right? So fill a data table each time

Comment: No - If the datatable contains all the data needed to populate the list boxes you just need to pass it to the method, and tell it what data member to use. See my edit above.